# How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS using .htaccess rules?

Tags: security, http, .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm trying to redirect all insecure **HTTP** requests on my site (e.g. `http://www.example.com`) to **HTTPS** (`https://www.example.com`). How can I do this in **.htaccess** file?

By the way, I'm using **PHP**.

Comment: You can (and should) do this through your `httpd`, not with PHP.

Comment: @jnpcl, while I agree the httpd solution is better that the PHP-based solution, I don't think a systematic redirection is a good practice in general. If you want to redirect your users to HTTPS at all times, send them there from the "entry point" (the first link to your site), don't do it half way through, which may leak some data that you'd think is protected (if you don't notice that instantaneous redirection).

Comment: @Bruno: I was thinking more along the lines of duplicated http requests, the potential for lost query strings, and the possibility of the user manually typing in `http://`

Comment: @jnpcl that's a good point indeed. I was merely suggesting that, while people tend to ask for this sort of redirect to improve the security of their site, often, it doesn't actually improve it (since it doesn't prevent the same request to go through plain HTTP first).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4083221/), [Force SSL/HTTPS with Zend Framework and mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1329647/), [Force SSL and WWW in .htaccess](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8833)

Comment: @outis: the first link you posted is _this_ question.

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Add the following inside your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: For newbies this shall redirect `example.com`, `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` and `www.example.com`, `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` - see other answers for removing the www

Comment: Your wording is too strong a damnation of this answer. In that link, Apache says: "If, for whatever reason, you still want to use `mod_rewrite`... you might use". And of course if you don't have access to the server config (99% of users) then this answer is good.

Answer (score 364):

The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) recommend against using a rewrite:

> To redirect `http` URLs to `https`, do the following:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     Redirect / https://www.example.com/
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     # ... SSL configuration goes here
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

This snippet should go into main server configuration file, **not** into `.htaccess` as asked in the question.

This article might have come up only after the question was asked and answered, but seems to be the current way to go.

Comment: Where can i find the main server *configuration file*

Comment: I like not having to duplicate the VirutalHost record for *:80 and *:443,  Chrome is happy with a padlock however Firefox says "Parts of the this page are not surecure (such as images). How to fix that??  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox

Answer (score 154):

I'd recommend with 301 redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 37):

As I was saying in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070262/how-in-htaccess-can-i-redirect-the-user-to-https-from-http-and-back-again/4071655#4071655), I'd suggest you avoid redirecting all HTTP requests to their HTTPS equivalent blindly, as it may cause you a false impression of security. Instead, you should probably redirect the "root" of your HTTP site to the root of your HTTPS site and link from there, only to HTTPS.

The problem is that if some link or form on the HTTPS site makes the client send a request to the HTTP site, its content will be visible, before the redirection.

For example, if one of your pages served over HTTPS has a form that says `<form action="http://example.com/doSomething">` and sends some data that shouldn't be sent in clear, the browser will first send the full request (including entity, if it's a POST) to the HTTP site first. The redirection will be sent immediately to the browser and, since a large number of users disable or ignore the warnings, it's likely to be ignored.

Of course, the mistake of providing the links that should be to the HTTPS site but that end up being for the HTTP site may cause problems as soon as you get something listening on the HTTP port on the same IP address as your HTTPS site. However, I think keeping the two sites as a "mirror" only increases the chances of making mistakes, as you may tend to make the assumption that it will auto-correct itself by redirecting the user to HTTPS, whereas it's often too late. (There were similar discussions in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729497/how-can-i-prevent-access-to-php-files-if-the-caller-isnt-using-https))

Answer (score 18):

#### HTML redirect approach.

It works, but it's not the best.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=https://www.example.com" />
```

#### PHP approach

```php
<?php
function redirectTohttps() {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on") {
        $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Location:$redirect"); 
    } 
}
?>
```

#### `.htaccess` approach

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

copied from:
[www.letuslook.org](https://www.letuslook.org/linux/redirect-http-to-https/)

Answer (score 15):

I found out that the best way for https and www on domain is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: there is no `HTTPS_HOST` variable available in Apache htaccess. Only `HTTP_HOST` can be used. Also, you could add `[OR]` at the end of first condition to make it overall more flexible, as now it could only redirect non-ssl non-www requests.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution depends on your requirements. This is a summary of previously posted answers with some context added.

If you work with the Apache web server and can change its configuration, follow the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

But you also asked if you can do it in a `.htaccess` file. In that case you can use Apache's [RewriteEngine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If everything is working fine and you want browsers to remember this redirect, you can declare it as permanent by changing the last line to:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But be careful if you may change your mind on this redirect. Browsers remember it for a very long time and won't check if it changed.

You may not need the first line `RewriteEngine On` depending on the webserver configuration.

If you look for a PHP solution, look at the [$_SERVER array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
if (!$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I like this method of redirecting from http to https. Because I don't need to edit it for each site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the following code in your .htaccess file automatically redirects visitors to the HTTPS version of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If you have an existing .htaccess file:

Do not duplicate RewriteEngine On.

Make sure the lines beginning RewriteCond and RewriteRule immediately follow the already-existing RewriteEngine On.

Comment: Thank you for the note on not duplicating the RewriteEngine On.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in a situation where your cannot access the apache config directly for your site, which many hosted platforms are still restricted in this fashion, then I would actually recommend a two-step approach.  The reason why Apache themselves document that you should use their configuration options first and foremost over the mod_rewrite for HTTP to HTTPS.

First, as mentioned above, you would setup your .htaccess mod_rewrite rule(s):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Then, in your PHP file(s) (you need to do this where ever it would be appropriate for your situation, some sites will funnel all requests through a single PHP file, others serve various pages depending on their needs and the request being made):

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') { exit(1); } ?>
```

The above needs to run BEFORE any code that could potentially expose secure data in an unsecured environment.  Thus your site uses automatic redirection via HTACCESS and mod_rewrite, while your script(s) ensure no output is provided when not accessed through HTTPS.

I guess most people don't think like this, and thus Apache recommends that you don't use this method where possible.  However, it just takes an extra check on the development end to ensure your user's data is secure.  Hopefully this helps someone else who might have to look into using non-recommended methods due to restrictions on our hosting services end.

Answer (score 3):

Do everything that is explained above for redirection. Just add "HTTP Strict Transport Security" to your header. This will avoid man in the middle attack.

> Edit your apache configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf and /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for example) and add the following to your VirtualHost:

```
# Optionally load the headers module:
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

<VirtualHost 67.89.123.45:443>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
</VirtualHost>
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper method of redirecting HTTP to HTTPS using .htaccess according to GoDaddy.com. The first line of code is self-explanatory. The second line of code checks to see if HTTPS is off, and if so it redirects HTTP to HTTPS by running the third line of code, otherwise the third line of code is ignored.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to the .htaccess file:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://[your domain name]%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Where [your domain name] is your website's domain name.

You can also redirect specific folders off of your domain name by replacing the last line of the code above with:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://[your domain name]/[directory name]%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect all `http` requests to `https` , you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

If mod-rewrite isn't enabled and you are on apache 2.4, you can also use a `Redirect` inside `if` directive to redirect `http` requests to `https` .

**Apache 2.4.**

```
<if "%{HTTPS} !~ /on/">
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need mod_rewrite for other things, using Apache core IF directive is cleaner & faster:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off'">
Redirect permanent / https://yoursite.com/
</If>
```

You can add more conditions to the IF directive, such as ensure a single canonical domain without the www prefix:

```
<If "req('Host') != 'myonetruesite.com' || %{HTTPS} == 'off'">
Redirect permanent / https://myonetruesite.com/
</If>
```

There's a lot of familiarity inertia in using mod_rewrite for everything, but see if this works for you.

More info: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

To see it in action (try without www. or https://, or with .net instead of .com): https://nohodental.com/ (a site I'm working on).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

(worked for me when none of the above answers worked)

Bonus:

```
ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
```

(fixed https://**www**.example.com not found)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all `.htaccess` configurations I could find on the internet but none worked.
Then, I realized [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) discourages using `mod_rewrite`.

My solution was to edit apache configuration files under the following folder:
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

You will have one mandatory file named `000-default.conf` and an ssl configuration file named `000-default-le-ssl.conf` (if you have installed ssl certificate from letsencrypt/certbot). However, these files can be named differently depending on the file names you provided when setting up the site.

In `000-default.conf`, I edited the following inside `<VirtualHost *:80>` as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

In `000-default-le-ssl.conf`, I edited the following inside `<VirtualHost *:80>` as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

No other redirection is needed.

Save the file then restart the apache server using `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

The above things are for the Apache server only. What if running PHP at tomcat?

So you can use PHP code, whether it is Apache/tomcat/Nginx etc...

```
if (!((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&   
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'))){
    $redirect = 'https://' . str_replace($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], 8443, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to get this to work on an EC2 instance without a load balancer since that costs money.  I've read everywhere that .htaccess isn't the "right" way to do it.  Obviously, it will work, but I was trying to keep things by the book.  I was following all of the examples to update the httpd.conf file and adding a lot of unnecessary stuff.  It turns out the only line you really need is this:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.yourdomain.com
```

My problem was that originally I had added this in a VirtualHost tag inside of httpd.conf, which is what a lot of posts tell you to do, but it wasn't working.  It turns out there was a separate conf file stored in /etc/httpd/conf.d called yourdomain.conf which already had the VirtualHost tag and was overriding my httpd.conf settings.  I just added the above line inside of it and voila, it instantly redirected to https.  There is no need for the separate VirtualHost for port 443.

It's working now and the VirtualHost tag looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/requests.log combined
    Redirect permanent / https://www.yourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: I already had TLS setup with a FREE certificate from certbot (Love those guys) and was just trying to redirect regular http calls to the working https site.

Comment: I conf file for your site doesn't exist until you add it. Presumably you had already done so and then you must have forgotten you did that.

Answer (score -1):

take this code to you .htaccess file 
[Redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically](https://www.name.com/support/articles/115005296088-Redirect-HTTP-to-HTTPS-automatically)

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it from the tomcat server follow the below steps

In a standalone Apache Tomcat (8.5.x) HTTP Server, how can configure it so if a user types [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), they will be automatically forwarded to https([www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)) site.

The 2 step method of including the following in your WEB-INF/web.xml before the closing  tag

```
step 1: 
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and setting the [Tomcat_base]/conf/server.xml connector settings:

```
step 2:
<Connector URIEncoding="utf-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
<SSLHostConfig>
<Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="[keystorelocation]" type="RSA" />
</SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Note: If you already did the https configuration and trying to redirect do step 1 only.

Answer (score -1):

Not only can you do this in your .htaccess file, you should be doing this period. You will also want to follow the steps [here](https://hstspreload.org) to get your site listed on the HSTS preload list after you implement this redirect so that any requests to the insecure http version of your website never make it past the user agent. Instead, the user agent checks the requested URI against a baked in list of https only websites and, if the requested URI is on that list, changes the protocol from http to https before transmitting the request to the server. Therefore, the insecure request never makes it out into the wild and never hits the server. Eventually when the internet changes over to https only the HSTS preload list will not be needed. Until then, every site should be using it.

In order to perform the redirect, we need to enable the rewrite engine and then redirect all traffic from the http port 80 to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourwebsite.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

After lots of tries by considering without www and with www this works this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?yourdomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

In the case of the http-to-https redirection, the use of RewriteRule would be appropriate if you don't have access to the main server configuration file, and are **obliged** to perform this task in a .htaccess file instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34387007)

Answer (score -2):

Through .htaccess This will help.

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Also, Refer this for More Detail. [How To Redirect Http To Https?](https://www.httptohttpsmigration.com/redirect-http-to-https/)

Answer (score -2):

This redirects all the URLs to https and www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No `HTTPS_HOST` variable is accessible in Apache `htaccess` by default. You can only use `HTTP_HOST`. Also your third condition is redundant, as first condition already filters out non-ssl requests.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Apache, mod_rewrite is the easiest solution, and has a lot of documentation online how to do that. For example: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html

Answer (score -3):

If you're using an Amazon Web Services Elastic Load Balancer which accepts https traffic and routes it to your server(s) with http, the correct way to redirect all http traffic to https is described here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb

Use the X-Forwarded-Proto header (contains http or https) which is always included in http requests from the load balancer, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

In the httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

Or in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

Bonus: it will not try to redirect http traffic on your local development machine.

Answer (score -3):

It works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

and for example, [http://server/foo?email=someone%40example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https/53107288#53107288) redirects normally without any issues.
The file .htaccess located in the website root folder (for example named public_html).
It is possible to use 
**RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$** instead **RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on**

Comment: Looks like the right answers the same as mine. Difference is only RewriteRule line **^(.*)$** instead **(.*)** and **[L,R=301]** in the end. Adding **<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>... </IfModule>** required to check if module mod_rewrite in an active state.