# Redirect http to https

Tags: php, .htaccess

I had a site http://www.test.com

Now i make the folder 'test' secure

So the site is avialable in https://www.test.com

My requirement is ,when some one type http://www.test.com ,

then it should go to https://www.test.com.

Is there any way using .Htaccess or any other method?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple method within PHP:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
  header('location: https://mydoamin.com');
  die();
}
```

htaccess method:

```
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "mydomain.com"
ErrorDocument 403 https://mydomain.com
```

Comment: Chris, why do you need the or `!$_SERVER['HTTPS']`? if it's already https why do you need to redirect it to https?

Comment: If you're already on HTTPS, then the superglobal `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` will be set.  If that variable is **not** set, then you are not on HTTPS, so you redirect.  Thus, `if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))` - in English, "If $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is NOT set..."

Answer (score 1):

In Apache2 configuration, you could use the redirect command :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    Redirect / https://www.test.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.the-domain-you-want-to-redirect-to.com"></HEAD>
<BODY>
Optional page text here.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

That should do it.

Comment: This does not seem to have any bearing on the question at all.