# Having Trouble Securing my site with SSL

Tags: ssl, e-commerce, ssl-certificate

I recently bought and installed a RapidSSL CA SSL Certificate and now I'm having a few problems. The site automatically loads the http site instead of the secured https site. When I manually enter in https://www.GetOmniTech.com I'm told that all pages are secured. I'm in the process of enabling eCommerce on this site, but I have to iron out these issues first. Could someone help me?

Comment: show us your webserver configuration. have you configured it to listen on port 80 or port 443?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite normal for the website to default to http. You just need to amend your hyperlinks to certain pages, like login forms for example, so that they point to https:// instead of using relative urls and ensure the form actions of those pages passes to https:// too.

Edit:
Also, looking in the source of your website I see that various resources are loaded in via http:// even when visiting the page on https://. You can resolve this easily by amending all absolute links like this to just prefix with // - for example href="//www.google...". This tells the browser to use the current mode instead of something fixed.