# How To Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

Today I turned on SSL.

But I have a big problem, i do not know how to set the absolute all subpages diverted permanently to: `https://example.com` in htaccess.

So I want all this:

- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`

to be redirected to `https://example.com`

Like **all subpages** (I have 300 sub pages).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works with every domain name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This does not work, perform redirection at: https: // www. I have a SSL only for this https: //

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: now works for example. com but it does not work for all sub-pages?

Comment: You need to make sure this rule is **very first rule**. This rule has `RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]` which mean it works for **all the pages**

Comment: I understand, but it does not work for all sublinks (for some works for some does not work).

Comment: If you test with `http://www.domain.com/foobar.html` that also gets redirected to `https`

Comment: Yes based on that only I left previous comment. `http://www.domain.com/foobar.html` redirects but `http://www.domain.com/index.html` doesn't. Do you have other rules also?

Comment: I do not understand. How do I do that all forward, not just a few pages?

Comment: What I mean is that rewrite is 100% correct since it is redirecting `http://www.domain.com/foobar.html` correctly. But you didn't answer my question. Can you copy/paste full .htaccess in question.

Comment: This is FULL htaccess:

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.MYDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://MYDOMAIN.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

Comment: Just realized you're using `nginx` and this rewrite rule is for Apache.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about nginx. I can only help with Apache rewrites.

Comment: Status of my server: cPanel Version  11.44.1 (build 15)
Theme  x3
Apache version  2.2.24
PHP version  5.4.15
MySQL version  5.5.37-cll
Architecture  x86_64
Operating system  linux

Comment: Your `http://` site is on nginx and `https://` is on Apache. I have checked with `curl` command line.

Comment: Dear anubhava,
What should I do if there is any possibility to do redirection, if you can help me?

Comment: You need to contact your hosting co. with this info and ask them to use Apache for both http and https sites.

Comment: Owners servers say that this is not possible, because the server uses both Apache and nginx

Comment: It has to use only one of it not both.

Comment: What should I do? If you could please help me?

Comment: I have already told you that only your server admins can help you resolving this. I have already suggested you correct and working rules but that would need Apache web server.

Comment: We contacted them, they do not know how to do.

Is there a possibility to buy and pay for a new server where http and moving him to apache, would that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes having Apache will definitely help. Meanwhile you can search Nginx help for redirecting http to https.

Comment: Dear, which version of my Nginx ?

Comment: I cannot find it out. Only your server admins can give you that info.