# htaccess wordpress https rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am hoping that you can help me with the htaccess rewrite rule below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

 # WPhtc: Begin Custom htaccess
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

I have recently changed my wordpress site from http to https... The problem is that old url's redirect to the domain name instead of the https version of that page

eg

if I access the following page `https://domain.com/test/testing/` it works 100%, now if I change the `https` part to `http` then the page redirects to `https://domain.com` instead of to `https://domain.com/test/testing/` how do I fix it so that if you go to the old version page `http://domain.com/test/testing/` (the not https version) that it redirects to `https://domain.com/test/testing/` instead of just the domain name `https://domain.com`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https

Comment: Have you changed site and home URL to `https://` in permalinks?

Comment: Hi Anubhava, yes I have done it... it works perfectly for https:// but as soon as you access an old link then it redirects to the home https:// version instead of the page in https format...

Comment: Can you test this in Firebug and see what redirects are showing up in `Net` tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find a workaround for `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` since this only represents the file that is accessed. But you obviously want to access the SSL vHost.
So you might hardcode the https into your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

[This](https://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html) might help you alot. (found the code above there)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling also with this issue and finally I found a solution for the home redirection and the wordpress in the same htaccess file, and finally it also works for old http links, redirecting to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution. It worked well, but if you do that you'll need to  manually change all your internal links.
This works better ;)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this .htaccess for wordpress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```