# Rewrite all HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

I have a website that used to work with `HTTP` for 12 years. Current database is about 6-7 years old with small modifications, but content is this old and all news entries have images inside it's content (it's news website).

Now I want to go for `HTTPS` but I have a problem. Images are requested over `HTTP` because links to images are stored this way in database.

Is there a way to make all these requests switch to `https` without actually going to database and changing all these links to https?

Current version of website is developed using Laravel 4.

I've already added this to `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: You can redirect them, but browsers will still complain about it because the initial request will go over http. Your only option is to change the hardcoded links (if you can make just links without a protocol or a domain this would be a plus).

Comment: As Wrikken said.  Your images shouldn't include `http:` for most cases.  `//` works for the current protocol, like: `//www.domain.com/img/image.jpg` or using the root path, like `/img/image.jpg`.

Comment: thanks. Its fairly obvious solution, but id didn't cross my mind. Will try it

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. A quick search with 'redirect' instead of 'rewrite' returns this: 
[How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

In summary:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```