# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a SSL on my site and would like to redirect all my http pages to https
I find something below and work for www.yourdomain.com.

If I also need transfer all yourdomain.com(without www) to https what should I add to htaccess? Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
<!-- Please put the redirect without www here, thanks-->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search reveals hundreds of results. For example, this [official FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS).

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Comment: Thank you! Could I only redirect those pages contain a keyword "purchasepage" on my entire domain?

Comment: Sure thing. Make a small effort, and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: mmm.. how to redirect all those pages with keyword for example "purchasepage"? Could you help me out?