# Web Browsers Don't Pick Up SSL Certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, web, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am setting up a ssl certificate for a website

http://www.wegetitall.ca

I have checked it with many different ssl checkers and everything is ok but neither chrome nor internet explorer pick it up. There is no lock sign in chrome and it doesn't even say the certificate is not secure, it just doesn't see it at all.

The certificate was bought from godaddy and more information about it can be found here: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.wegetitall.ca

What could be the reasons it doesn't show?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me on Chrome 45: https://i.imgur.com/ZbEjkpm.png. You may want to server-side-redirect the `http` version of the URL to the `https` version if that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see SSL connection with your website.
When you connect to your website, make sure you type https:// .... NOT http://

if the connection is http, you can redirect to https.
Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https) for redirecting (it's based on a server with PHP running. Find the correct one that's applicable to you).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SSL is installed well you just need to redirect to HTTPS
Put following code in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.wegetitall.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```