# how change htaccess code, force my url to https

Tags: .htaccess, https

Hello and sorry about my english, im german!
I found this htaccess on github:
https://gist.github.com/HechtMediaArts/ad6cb1f190279f9eca7d

I would like to force the url to https? Which part of code i have to change?
Thanks a lot for reading!

On [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https) is a similar question, but i cant use it. I dont know which part of code i have to cancel to use it for my site.

Comment: Do you have embedded links in your code with http://blahblahblah.... or does the code all use relative paths like /lib/blah/blah?  If you have embedded http:// in the code, that will need to be fixed first.  Otherwise it's relatively straight forward:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Comment: No alex, that is not a duplicate. I tried to find the part, which i should change, but i cant.
On your link i see the code, but which i have to change? Thats my question!

Comment: I tried also to add your code from the link, but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution:
Between the Lines 166 and 167
insert this Code:

```
# Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks to all!