# How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS on magento

Tags: .htaccess, http, magento, https, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect all the insecure `HTTP` requests to `HTTPS` on magento.

**For example :**
My site name is : http://www.mysite.nl/
I want to redirect it to : https://www.mysite.nl/

Also i want to redirect all its sub-pages and categories to `HTTPS`.

**For example :**
Shop page is : http://www.mysite.nl/shop/
I want to redirect it to : https://www.mysite.nl/shop/

Here is my magento configuration for `HTTPS` and I am sure there is no any issue with it. - http://prntscr.com/ah9o2p

My `.htaccess` file :
http://textuploader.com/5no6v

I have tried to add some tweak in `.htaccess` file but it doesnt work :
1. [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Is there anyone help me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Change your secure and insecure url form admin panel by going into system->confriguration->general->web and change it form there. Apply new url with https

Comment: thanks for your replay but have you check the screenshot i have attached above.? : http://prnt.sc/ah9o2p

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

inset this in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

First of all select your database from phpmyadmin.
Run this command on sql section of phpmyadmin

> select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';

You will see all base urls used on magento. Now, to change the base url execute this command on sql section.

> update core_config_data set value = 'http://www.mysite.nl/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'; update core_config_data set value = 'https://www.mysite.nl/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';

The second one will generate secure url with https on your domain.