# Wordpress - How to get my media back after changing to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, media

I recently changed my Wordpress website's URL from HTTP to HTTPS but unfortunatly, the pictures of the library are no longer available. The library is showing the list of all my medias, but it's empty. Is there a way to find them automatically or should I reupload them one by one ?
Thanks

I also changed my media's URL to HTTPS too, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

- This bug had been in wordpress for a while. Not sure when wordpress could fix or automate this issue => https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/336358/site-not-reachable-due-to-change-from-http-to-https
- This bug is relates to db or wordpress core files. And reproduction of this bug, is upload media while have site url/wordpress url like http://example.com or https://example.com then change site URL and wordpress URL with http://example.net or https://example.net. Open any page where media was embedded; You will notice this would break links of media

Coming to solution there might be different ways to fix it depending on what’s your environment for wordpress is. There are different possibilities.

- If wordpress site is small to mid scale, then open pages/post and re-update attachment or media file and this will replace broken link with new link. You can use developer mode in browser to check which attachment are poping broken. Don’t upload or remove attachment, that will be time taking.
- If wordpress site large or complicated with media file, if you have access to VPS or webserver (apache or nginx) then you can create redirect from http://example.com to https://example.com so that your broken link still able to redirect at webserver level. This method you wouldn’t require to update manually all links within wordpress because webserver will handle redirect. You can google about it. For apache follow this => [Wordpress http to https redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069784/wordpress-http-to-https-redirection)
- If you managing wordpress via godaddy, hostinger etc, perhaps check their support article on creation redirect or rewrite policy for wordpress instance or create support ticket since you paying for such support to them. And let them handle redirect or rewrite query.
- If you have any sort CDN (cloudflare, or Cloudfront) on front, you can create policy of redirect on top of it or enable http to https
- Optionally If you using elementor on wordpress, then you could use replace url feature, to change all embedded link.

I hope my answer will able to narrow down the issue.