# HTTP in WordPress functions want to avoid https redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have transferred the site from HTTP to HTTPS, what i have done so far is :
1. Added FORCE SSL in wp-config.php
2. Edited the .htaccess.
3. Updated the links in Settings > General, site url and other one.
4. Tried various SSL plugins.

But still, wp_nav_menu is using HTTP and onclick it redirects to HTTPS, i don't want that redirection and instead simple by default HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to just redirect all of you site to the https version.
See here e.g.: [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Next you need to make sure that the links generated by your content management system link to https version where they use absolute links, that's what you already seem to have done as far as I can tell.