# Best way to redirect 301 to https & www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, web, https

I want to redirect 301:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

TO

```
https://www.example.com
```

I put this code, but it does not work (error 500)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off           [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L, NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Source: [this blog](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/05/redirect-browser-https-ssl-php.html)

OR

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798882/2142994):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ani Menon!

Comment: What about this?
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.texel.es/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^texel.es
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.texel.es/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: which file is the "main server configuration file" and where is it located??