# .htaccess with http to https

Tags: http, https

Hello so i have just got a SSL Certificate for my site. I am redirecting all links to https:// as you can imagine, I am trying to use .htaccess to redirect

```
mylink.co.uk, 
www.mylink.co.uk, 
http://mylink.co.uk, 
http://www.mylink.co.uk
```

to 
`https://www.mylink.co.uk`

no matter what link from the list

```
"mylink.co.uk, www.mylink.co.uk, http://mylink.co.uk, http://www.mylink.co.uk"
```

it must redirect back to `https://www.mylink.co.uk` also i am using Opencart i have changed my config files and everythings pointed to HTTPS Apart from the redirect does not work

Comment: try to search first....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)