# HTTPS configuration for OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel-5.3, octobercms

Hi everyone here I am again. I have been looking for the correct https configuration for october so that when visitors type www.mywebsite.com, the brower will assume `https://` to be the beginning instead.

I changed the `linkPolicy` to `secure` (I tried `force` too but not sure where is the `app.url` that it mentioned in the comment) and `'backendForceSecure'` to `true`, it works on when I access www.mywebsite.com/backend (automatically access via https) but not www.mywebsite.com (still access via http). Please help.

Comment: Cant you use .htaccess for that?

Comment: @dragontree I do not think that helps but thanks for your input. There should be some configuration that we can set I believe...

Comment: As far as I know, there there is currently no such setting for the frontend in OctoberCMS, that is why I suggested using htaccess

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot for your information. Really hope that OctoberCMS will be improved for these common requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.

1- Enable debug mode:

in config/app.php

'debug' => true,

2- Clear cache

3- Add those lines, in the .htaccess file at the root of your site :

```
    ## Force secure connection
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

4- Modifiy the app.url in the /web/config/app.php file

```
    'app.url' => 'https://...',
```

Answer (score 0):

Still no solution for configure https in October CMS? I have nginx shared hosting with Let's encrypt certificate and `linkPolicy='secure'` still not work properly. 
How this CMS want to be popular if such a "small" problem can't be fix for 2 years (just check official forum and threads like "Routing over SSL", "Forcing SSL" etc.
Using .htaccess is only workaround. 
F. ex. how to solve this in nginx (without .htaccess)? Buy another server?

Comment: OctoberCMS is a very good CMS in my opinion but there is still a lot of space to be improved. I am also struggling a lot in looking for answers for some issues but no luck...

Comment: And I dont think it is proper to ask questions by answering people's questions in Stackoverflow. You can choose to comment on it like what I do now instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess or configure your apache or ngix to use https and redirect all traffic to https.
ngix: https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom

apache [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Use htst headers

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet

In `path/to/october/config/app.php` set your `url` value to a https domain.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I yet to have the chance to try that out.