# Http to Https not working for inner pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, https

I have made all necessary changes to convert to https but not working for inner page.

Here is my .htaccess

```
# Use PHPBETA Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpbetas .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.ae/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note: It is working for home/main page like https://example.com. It says its secure. But when i visit https://example.com/otherPage it says insecure.

Note: My website is developed in CodeIgniter. I also changed url in config.php file.

Ref: I followed all these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Any Idea??

Comment: for inner pages check any resources like `css,js or images` coming with `http` url. if any resource coming with `http` it will not showing secure. All the resource load with `https` URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I am using in codeigniter. Also make sure you used `base_url()` or `site_url()` in linking nav.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make all your `css, js images` on your page come from `https` URL too, this will resolve your issue.