# How to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS using an .htaccess file in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to redirect my WordPress site to HTTP to HTTPS through .htaccess file.
(e.g. http://www.example.com) to (e.g. https://www.example.com)
Please help me out to do that.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/6244709

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https

Comment: Thanks @Picard it's working for me Great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to the https in wordpress. And wordpress ttake over your all requests.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Here why you mention the blog in Rewrite rule i am unable understand that.