# awstat for http and https url

Tags: ssl, joomla, cpanel

In my Joomla 3.7 website, I have set to force entire site https in Joomla control panel. But when I am checking awstat in cpanel, there are bandwidth consumption for both http and https. The data use for http is 1/3 of SSL data use.

Is this unsecured data transfer normal or there is something to be fixed? Please help.

Comment: You can do force redirect all http request to https by .htaccess file, after that all request will be land to only https only

Comment: I am confused how to do this. This QA recommends against rewrite rules in .htaccess file. Please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https