# HTTP redirect not redirecting

Tags: apache, http, https, ubuntu-server, server-configuration

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https/21798882#21798882), I am using the following code in the Apache configuration file (default-ssl.conf in this case)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName name.domain.com
    Redirect / https://name.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I've restarted Apache and... nothing. No error, no redirect. Http is served as http, https is served as https. What did I do wrong? My domain name doesn't start with "www" but I can't imagine that making a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, Also some time the browsers dose DNS cache try clearing it, in chrome you can goto chrome://net-internals/#dns and clear it, or use another browser to test.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/webroot/example.com/htdocs

  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  <Directory /home/webroot/example.com/htdocs>
    FileETag MTime Size
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  RewriteEngine on
  Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

  ErrorLog /home/webroot/example.com/logs/error_log
  CustomLog /home/webroot/example.com/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/webroot/example.com/htdocs

  ServerName www.example.com

  RewriteEngine on
  Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

  ErrorLog /home/webroot/example.com/logs/error_log
  CustomLog /home/webroot/example.com/logs/access_log combined
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's having no effect either (either positive or negative). Definitely not a DNS cache problem.  It seems that everything between <VirtualHost *:80> and </VirtualHost> is being ignored...

Comment: I have edited my answer have a look if that helps, also don't forget to restart httpd

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realised what the problem was. default-ssl.conf  is only used for configuration with ssl, and is too late to tell it anything about http at that stage. The code you describe, if placed in 000-default.conf (ubuntu server 14.4) works however.

Comment: Ooh  that's a shame, I am not much familiar to Ubuntu