# Apache url rewrite for http to https across aws elb

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, httpd.conf

I am trying my whole domain redirect from http to https across aws elastic load balancer.

My urlrewrite.conf (Apache/2.2.15)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/testdemo/
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /web/testcontroller?url=$1 [PT]
```

The above rules is redirecting home page from http to https. But after entering the testdemo virtual directory getting file "404 Not Found"

Can anyone tell me the what is the issue.

Comment: It's better to use a redirect: [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798882/1807667)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/testdemo/
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /web/testcontroller?url=$1 [PT]
```

After removing "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$" condition, things started working as expected.