# Redirect www to non-www, http to https and only one Host

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a special redirect system (htaccess) for improving SEO and the indexed structure of a website in google.

There are some Domains, who pointing to Website root directory. Therefore the Websites gets delivered by multiple Domains.

Specification for the Redirect System:

- http -> https
- www -> non-www
- redirect to one host
- only one 301 redirect (no several redirect behind each others)

Example:

Main Domain: domain-a.com

Goal: https://domain-a.com/XXX

**Please look as this example Set**

[>>> Redirect Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX5jQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just google same answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)?

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello Turar, thanks for your quick answer. But it is a standard answer everywhere to find in the Internet. 3 of the 4 wanted specifications not solved with this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

# other domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain-a.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://domain-a.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect to domain with HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Same for www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://domain-a.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot shushu304 this solution is absolutely correct!

Comment: great :)   you are welcome to accept this answer ;)