# Very slow https redirect - Adds 10 seconds to load time

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, https

I am experience wait times of up to 12 seconds due to the ssl redirect.  I've tried may things and can't seem to figure out why.  It seems to be the worst when using 'www.thesoapopera.com.'

Almost twelve seconds with www.thesoapopera.com:
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/BBsdZ/www.thesoapopera.com

1.13 Seconds with the full https://www.thesoapopera.com:
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cPx3LD/https://www.thesoapopera.com

Almost back to back tests and the website takes 10 seconds longer to load!  Here is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} 
!wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=aacc|aaWoocommerce|acd4494|KenzieTrezise|Luna
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=Sean|Stacey|Steppe
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.thesoapopera.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ! 
(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wp_woocommerce_session
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/spscannell/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN WEBPWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/spscannell/public_html/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/$1.webp" [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>
AddType image/webp .webp
# END WEBPWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN EWWWIO

# END EWWWIO

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 90
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 512M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of direct access to the `https://` site no cookie is send yet and the response is comparably small: only 20KByte. In case of access to `http://` this site provides a cookie which then gets sent on the redirect to the `https://` site which results in a much larger response of 121 KByte.

My guess is that the application logic does a lot of database lookups if a session cookie is send which results both in a longer time needed to create the response and also in a different and larger content. Also, you can see that the `https://` version results in only 50 total requests while the `http://` version results in 77 requests, i.e. more requests are done (probably because of different content served) which additionally impacts the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping all your rewrites in one single IfModule section, of course keeping the SSL redirection first as it is now, but the [correct syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083233/7748072) :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```