# Http to Https Not all conditions work OR ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect **www.example.com** or **example.com** to https://www.example.com

I've tried

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But it gives me  an error
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

I also tried

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)(:80)? [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  order deny,allow
```

It works fine for **example.com**,

but not for **www.example.com**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Comment: How is your SSL cert managed? Is it installed directly on the application server or are you using an SSL proxy? Your first code snippet should not result in a redirect loop, unless you are behind a proxy. The fact that your first rule results in a redirect loop suggests you are behind an SSL proxy.

Comment: HEY, if you are using the aws server then you can use the route53 for this problem.

Comment: we will go for Rewrite Engine for this reason.  " the element after the domain name. It, too, should be relevant, appropriate, professional, memorable, easy to spell and readable. And for the same reasons: to attract customers and improve in search ranking." so your problem related to domain name .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've talked with my hosting provider and they replied :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You may use the following lines to force both HTTPS and WWW :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.YOURDOMAIN.COM$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.YOURDOMAIN.COM/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I see 'ENV'. I don't know What it means but it works fine :D

Comment: The `ENV` prefix references an _environment_ variable called `HTTPS` instead of the "normal" _server_ variable `HTTPS` that you referenced in your question. The `ENV:HTTPS` is being set by your host and implies your host is using some kind of front-end proxy to manage the SSL cert.