# URL Rewriting http > https AND domain.tld > www.domain.tld

Tags: apache, url, https, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite and redirect my `http:\\www.domain.tld` to `https:\\www.domain.tld`

And I want to rewrite and redirect my `domain.tld` to `www.domain.tld`

I want to have something that redirect and, with seo concern, shows that's a redirection.

For now I have something like this:

1)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,QSA]
```

or

2)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,QSA]
```

What's the best? Is there something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Questions about that are answered every week, do so research, there are **many** working configurations detailed out there.

Comment: :-/ sorry but I didn't find this example (with www) and i struggle to apply the other examples I found... so I wanted just to know if what i propose is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache docs recommend against using a rewrite: [redirect to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https/21798882#21798882)

To redirect http URLs to https, you should do the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com
# ... SSL configuration goes here
```

This snippet should go into main server configuration file, **not** into .htaccess as asked in the question.

But if you don't have access to the main server configuration file you could use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Line 1: if the url starts without www

line 2: if there is no https

line 3: rewrite all urls from this domain to one that starts with https and have www

Comment: Seems good, i'll try it this afternoon. Thank you to take the time to answer me.