# Redirect http to https with www using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https, server

How can I redirect HTTP to https include WWW using `.htaccess`?

Example :

> 1. redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com
> 2. redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
> 3. redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

I'm trying

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show us what have you tried!

Comment: @M.K post updated with code

Comment: Please don't use unneccessary tags - this question is in no way related to JS, PHP, or HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Comment: @NicoHaase this not duplicate. you can call it similar question & i use the tag which stackoverflow suggest me.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your use case and the one in the other question? I see none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the following code inside your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This `.htaccess` file will redirect http://example.com/ to https://example.com/.

**Code Explanatio**n:

- `[NC]` matches both upper and lower case versions of the URL
- The `X-Forwarded-Proto` (XFP) header is a de-facto standard header for identifying the protocol

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 //If you want the condition to match port
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Try in this. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Please add some explanation to these rules - "try this" does not help the OP to learn what you've changed and why this change makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to these rules - "try this" does not help the OP to learn what you've changed and why this change makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

[APACHE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26484741/3851720)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

NGINX

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /srv/www/example.com/keys/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/www/example.com/keys/www.example.com.key;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

You can replace ssl on; directive with listen 443 ssl; as recommendation from [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl).