# Redirect www.domain.com to https://www.domain

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, redirect, safari

Currently having problem: if I send someone a link, for example www.domain.com and he clicks it, default browser Safari or Opera is opened but site cant be reached, If that same browser I alter domain with https:// in front of it, then website is loaded well.

There is no problem with loading from chrome.

So as I guess there is a problem with redirection from www. to https://www.

My website is wordpress, and hosted on aws. Please suggest with further actions.

Comment: Are you using Apache or NGINX?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

Apache servers: virtual host file(httpd.conf)

1. Open your Apache configuration file. Possible locations include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (Apache 2/httpd), /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ (Apache 2.4), or /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (Apache on Ubuntu).
2. Add a rewrite rule to the VirtualHost section of your configuration file similar to the following:

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
   RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
3. Save your Apache configuration file.
4. Restart Apache.