# How to Redirect a Folder to a Plain Domain using HTTPS in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have a domain "http://www.example.com" that points to a Folder on the host, I need to redirect to corresponding HTTPS using .htaccess.

What .htaccess files has is this:

```
<IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler php-stable .php
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  FcgidWrapper /etc/apache2/gs-bin/php-stable-wrapper .php
  <Files *.php>
    Options +ExecCGI
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```

And what I've added is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have not succeeded,

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Comment: It's different, I need to access with Https to a Folder inside public_html

Comment: only writing the domain

Answer (score -1):

Well I found the solution, I had to create an .htaccess in that folder with the same code.

Comment: Please share the file `.htaccess` so that others may learn from your question and solution.