# Redirect HTTP domain to HTTPS domain via htaccess file code

Tags: wordpress, redirect, domain-name

Please let me know how I can redirect http domain to https domain hassle free via htaccess file. I want to redirect this domain

> http://example.in to https://example.com

domain.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn’t recommend to use this in the .htaccess, you can read about it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect).

You should use this instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

In case that you want to use .htaccess anyway you need to use the next rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```