# SSL with PHP redirect

Tags: javascript, php, ssl

mysite.com has a valid ssl Certificate. 
On mysite.com there is this Code:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href ='"mysite.com"'
```

(edit:)
I found out that window.location.href indeed points to mysite.com but that Link is then forwarded with a proxy pass to othersite.com (while the URL from mysite.com is still shown).

Does othersite.com also need a valid SSL Certificate?

Comment: If you don't specify the `http:` protocol, it will default to the same protocol as the current page, and if you used `https:` to get to the current page, it will try to access the other site with `https:` as well.

Comment: ok thanks! I found out the link points to mysite.com but that Link is forwarded with a proxy pass to othersite.com (while the URL from mysite.com is still shown). Does othersite.com need an SSL Certificate in this instance?

Comment: You should configure your webserver so it only serves the website over `HTTPS` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Comment: Are you trying Domain masking? Check this: https://serverfault.com/questions/279939/ssl-and-domain-masking

Answer (score -1):

By default, a standard **Single-name SSL Certificate** can secure only one domain. A **Wildcard SSL Certificate** can secure domain and sub-domains as well (e.g. example.com and www.example.com and blog.example.com)

If you want to secure multiple domains using a single certificate, you need a Multi-Domain (SAN) Certificate.

(Source: [dnsimple.com](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ssl-certificates-types/#ssl-certificates-by-secured-domains))

Comment: This does not answer OP's question

Comment: @DarkBee Can you please tell me why my answer is not helpful?

Comment: This only explains what types of `SSL` certificates there are, this is now what OP asked. OP is trying to redirect to a https page on the website (with js)

Comment: His question is not about how to redirect. His final question is "Does othersite.com also need a valid SSL Certificate?". That's why I have given info about types of SSL. I don't see any valid reason for the downvote.

Comment: well I appreciate your answer. I now understood that my actual question was something different.