# Set HTTPS as default

Tags: http, ssl, url, redirect, https

I've just got an SSL certificate for my website, but as default when I just write down *mywebsite.com* the browser brings me to *http://mywebsite.com* instead of *https://mywebsite.com*.

Googling I found people saying to redirect from the old URLs to the secure ones, but how can I? Should I check for every single page whether or not my website is on a secure URL?

Furthermore, visiting SSL protected websites and opening their source code, I can't even look at *view-source:http://securewebsite.com*, because it redirects me to *view-source:https://securewebsite.com* (it wouldn't do so with a simple redirect to the new URL).

So how can I make every visit to *mywebsite.com* a visit to the secure website and not the unsecure one?

EDIT:
I'm using a `register.it` domain and hosting it from `000webhost.com`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Comment: Additionally, please don't use irrelevant tags. Your question has completely no connection to PHP or HTML

Comment: @NicoHaase I thought at making a redirect using `meta refresh` or `header` when I am on an unsecure URL

Comment: .....and why not do that if you have already thought about that?

Comment: @NicoHaase beacuse, as I said, visiting famous secure website I get redirected even looking at the source code, and it wouldn't happen so if I use HTML or PHP redirect

Comment: @NicoHaase furthermore, it seems a bit awkward a check to the URL for every single page, so I asked if there was a better way to do so

Comment: You should mention what you're using to build and host your website so that people can give you more specific help.

Comment: @porglezomp I'm using a register.it domain and hosting it from 000webhost.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below code in you **.htaccess** file on root.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: It seems to work... Can I ask you what does `%{SERVER_PORT} 80` mean and why `$1` at the end of the URL?

Comment: $1 = Because if anyone access subpages with only "HTTP"
It will be automatically redirected to "HTTPS" with the same page.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer by editing - why do you check for any arbritrary port and not for the `%{HTTPS}` flag?