# how to redirect http urls to https url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

When I enter the url it will redirect to http://www.xyz.in, but if I edit it to https://www.xyz.in, the SSL certificate starts working.

The problem is how to redirect to https://www.xyz.in when the user enters xyz.in

Config file:

```
$root = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?xyx.in
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have tried changing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to `on`, but it always redirects to http://xyz.in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I think changing `(.*)` to `^` should work out. Let me know if it doesn't. Also, make sure mod_rewrite is enabled. Clear your browser's cache and try this.

Comment: Try again with HTTPS set to !on

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xyz.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Try this out. It should work.